# @react-google-maps/api using window.google.maps causing a Type error - how can I call the google maps API correctly?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am using `@react-google-maps/api` package. All works well. Example of working code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TemplatePage from '../templates/TemplatePage';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';

const containerStyle = {
  width: '400px',
  height: '400px'
};

const center = {
  lat: -3.745,
  lng: -38.523
};

const lat = 25.52
const lng = 52.25


export class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <TemplatePage>

        <LoadScript
          googleMapsApiKey="mykey"
        >
          <GoogleMap
            mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
            center={center}
            zoom={10}
          >

            <Marker
              position={{
                lat,
                lng
              }}
            >
            </Marker>
          </GoogleMap>
        </LoadScript>

      </TemplatePage>
    )
  }
}


export default Home;
```

Until the moment I am trying to get the custom icon for a marker:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TemplatePage from '../templates/TemplatePage';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import markerStation from'../../img/marker-station.png';

const containerStyle = {
  width: '400px',
  height: '400px'
};

const center = {
  lat: -3.745,
  lng: -38.523
};

const lat = 25.52
const lng = 52.25


export class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <TemplatePage>

        <LoadScript
          googleMapsApiKey="mykey"
        >
          <GoogleMap
            mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
            center={center}
            zoom={10}
          >

            <Marker
              position={{
                lat,
                lng
              }}
              icon={
                new window.google.maps.MarkerImage(
                  markerStation,
                  null, /* size is determined at runtime */
                  null, /* origin is 0,0 */
                  null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
                  new window.google.maps.Size(48, 48)
                )
              }
            >
            </Marker>
          </GoogleMap>
        </LoadScript>

      </TemplatePage>
    )
  }
}


export default Home;
```

So in short adding this piece of code into Marker component:

```
              icon={
                new window.google.maps.MarkerImage(
                  markerStation,
                  null, /* size is determined at runtime */
                  null, /* origin is 0,0 */
                  null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
                  new window.google.maps.Size(48, 48)
                )
              }
```

Will cause following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')
```

This is clearly pointing to the fact I am calling window.google.maps.MarkerImage

My question is how do I correctly use a call to the google API then?

Comment: Might need to install [@types/google.maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google.maps)?

Comment: There are custom marker icon examples at https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#marker

Comment: @jpoehnelt Thanks for the reply. I have tried it, but it does not resolve the issue. Same error as before. Thanks

Comment: @alpakyol Thank you for the reply. Yes, that is true and I am using it. The only part that I need and is not in there is defining the size of the icon. So currently I am using it like so: icon={
        new window.google.maps.MarkerImage(
          markerCompetitor,
          null, /* size is determined at runtime */
          null, /* origin is 0,0 */
          null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
          new window.google.maps.Size(48, 48)
        )
      }, unfortunately, I don't see where I could set the icon size in the documentation.

Comment: Check out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions.icon . There is no definition like `MarkerImage` (probably deprecated according to my search).

Comment: @alpakyol Yes, it is working as long as I add the key to the index.html, which I want to move away from for many reasons. The only problem is I don't see anywhere I could use the sizing of the image in the @react-google-maps/api

Comment: You can give size in `google.maps.Icon` object which `Marker` object in `react-google-maps-api` package can accept as type

Comment: @alpakyol Yes and that is what is not working and why I created this question in the first place :). See the code above ;) Any reference to window.google.maps or google.maps will throw the error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')`

Comment: Have you tried without using `window` (as typed in the examples in documentation). Just as `google.maps.Icon` (MarkerImage will also throw error).

Comment: @alpakyol Yes, I did. That was the first idea I had to try.